# drupal 7 Query database and display results after form submit in custom module

Tags: drupal

```
function mymodule_search_form($form, &$form_state) {

  $form..... define the form here

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'Search',
  );

  return $form;
}

function mymodule_search_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {

  //process the form and get result 
  $output = this is the result with a table of data.
  //I want to display the result table here.

 //Now I can only use drupal message to display on top.
 drupal_set_message($output);

  return;
}
```

So basically I want to have a form to search something from database.
Once click the submit to search, and get the result.

I want to display the result just under the form in the same form page.
**Do not go to another page, just in the original form page.**

The form can be clean/reset into original status, which is fine.

http://drupal.org/node/542646
This discussion is what I want, but there looks no solid result/solution there.

Answer (score 10):

You can stash the output table in the `$form_state`, set the form to rebuild, and display it if it exists in the original form function, e.g.

```
function mymodule_search_form($form, &$form_state) {

  $form..... define the form here

  if (!empty($form_state['results_table'])) {
    $form['results_table'] = array('#markup' => $form_state['results_table']);
  }

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'Search',
  );

  return $form;
}

function mymodule_search_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $form_state['results_table'] = function_to_get_table();
  $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Tested. Worked well.

Comment: Thanks a ton.It helped.And worked very well.but it did not work with Ajax submit button. Still resolved the issue.